# Order of operands in compare with std::map

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, stdmap

Say I have:

```
bool operator<(Type const& lhs, Type const& rhs) { /* ... */ }
std::map<Type, void*> m;
```

If I now do

```
Type t{};
m.find(t);
```

will `t` always end up in the left-hand side argument of `operator<` and the elements of `m` it is compared against in the right-hand side argument (or vice versa)?

Or is this implementation dependent and could go either way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, it can be *proved* that there are cases where it must be evaluated on both sides. This is because the mathematical equality

*a = b*

(which a dictionary must eventually decide upon) is simulated through

*not (a < b) and not (b < a)*.

Answer (score 5):

There is no stated guarantee either way, and in practice you can expect to find your operand on either side of the comparison, because the operation ultimately needs to observe `¬(A<B) && ¬(B<A)` to determine equality between `A` and `B`.

Make your operator as abstract as possible so that it does not matter. Make it consider only the values of the two arguments it receives, without any knowledge of any container or find operation.